# Rails character encoding different between rake & console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-console

I have a rake task that pulls some data from a MS SQL db, and recently I noticed that some special characters get encoded as a question mark '?'. While trying to dig into this issue, I realized that I could only repo it as a rake task, but not from the console.

Here is a snippet of what the code looks like:

```
 
require 'dbi'

namespace :db do 
  task :test => :environment do 
    db2 = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=x.x.x.x;PORT=1433;DATABASE=MyDB;TDS_VERSION=8.0;UID=user_id;PWD=pass")              
    rows = db2.execute('select * from Topic where id = 123')
    rows.each { |r| puts r['name'] }
    rows.finish
  end
end
```

when I run this as:

```
 rake RAILS_ENV=production db:test
```

it produces:

```
The Devil?s Tail
```

But when I run the exact same commands using:

```
/> script/console production
```

I get

```
The Devil`s Tail
```

Notice the back tick? Anyone have any idea why may be causing this? I double checked the ENV variables, and they both have LANG: en_US.UTF-8

EDIT

Forgot to mention I am using ruby 1.8.7p72 and Rails 2.3.4

Comment: What is the value of `r['name'].encoding` in both cases?

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7, so I get an undefined method `encoding'